# How can I get this custom middleware to run when an error occurs in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

Hello totally awesome cool beautiful people! I am trying to get this custom middleware function to run upon an error. I am using express and I have a custom middleware function which should run when a new error is thrown.

All of this is written in express. I have read the docs and am still struggling to get this correct. Here is the middleware function.

```
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log("running error handler middleware")
    const statusCode = res.statusCode ? res.statusCode : 500
    res.status(statusCode)
    res.json({
        message: err.message,
        stack: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? null : err.stack
    })
}


module.exports = errorHandler
```

Here is my entry point

```
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const colors = require('colors')
const errorHandler = require('./middleware/errorMiddleware')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()

connectDB()


//these lines of middleware allow us to grab info from the req.body
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.use('/api/goals', require('./routes/goalRoutes'))
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/userRoutes'))

//pulling in our error handler middleware
app.use(errorHandler)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`)
})
```

I have confirmed my file structure is correct and I am pulling the middleware in from the correct location. I have also made sure to place my app.use(errorHandler) at the bottom of my code to ensure it is the last error handler to run.

As of now when I encounter an error, my application crashed completely and does not return a json response with a stack trace.

This is going to cause issues later when trying to send errors back to the client side.

I can always go back to manually defining them through res.status(statusCode).json({message}) but this is the "node" way of doing things and does not implement the express syntax of "throw new Error(message)"

Any ideas on how to get a json response out of this without the app crashing while still using custom error handling and express throw new Error?

Thank you so much for the time, I appreciate it!

Comment: Okay, I solved this by wrapping all of my controlled functions in express-async-handler.

Comment: Here is what I believe the problem to be. When dealing with async errors, we have to use try catch statements in order to get the error to run. Using async handler allows us to omit these try catch block and to just focus on the success path.